# .bat coding or some app maybe?

Tags: batch-file

how can I organize my directories automatically?, I have a "downloads" folder, which currently contains lots of different info, for example, work related info, tv-shows, movies, etc, software, etc.

How can I automatically, maybe using some .bat execution, not sure, check for example the name of the files, or the type, and put them in the right subfolders?.

Thanks!.

Comment: There's more than one way to skin a cat, but python's windows support is good, so I tend to use that for any shell type scripting.

Comment: Since this is a one time organization, I'd recommend just doing it manually. Any script you write is going to be tedious with all of the rules you'll need. Unless it's _very_ basic like all *.wpd, doc, pdf, xls go into work. All image and video go into play, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `move` command to move files. You can also use wildcards in it.

So you could write a batch script that looks something like this:

```
cd C:\Users\You\Downloads
rem Excel sheets are work.
move *.xls Work
rem Reports are work.
move Report*.pdf Work\Reports
rem Pron and other viewing material ;)
move *.mp4 Private
```

You could run this script automatically by making it a scheduled job. Note that this script changes to the right directory first and then moves items to a relative subdirectory. This means that the directories Work, Work\Reports and Private must exist in the Downloads directory.

Of course you can expand the script to make it check and create directories as well, or you can specify different paths if you want to move the files out of the Downloads directory.

Basically, try to do it on the command line and then try to generalize those steps into your script.

Answer (score 0):

This batch file will create a set of folders like .mkv .jpg .mp3 using the filetypes inside the folder, and move the files into the appropriate folders.

Launch it from your desktop and change the "c:\media" to the right folder name.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\media" && for %%a in (*) do md "%%~xa" 2>nul & move "%%a" "%%~xa" >nul
```